# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS slow grub on virtual box

Tags: 14.04, grub2, virtualbox, bitnami

What could the reasons be for grub to be extremely slow for ubuntu 14.04 LTS when running on virtualbox? It takes 10+ seconds just to render the background image (bitnami logo). Changing boot options with the direction keys also takes several seconds to highlight the selected option. Not a disastrous issue but still quite annoying. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you enabled hardware virtualization in the BIOS/EFI firmware settings?

Comment: yes. it is enabled.